# How to get the data from Firebase realtime database to ListView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

```
-Quiz
  -MCQ
    -Question
       -1831
         -783444
           -//still got data
         -234567
           -//still got data
```

Above is my Firebase realtime database and I want only show the `783444` and `234567` to my `ListView` and clickable to next activity.

Please give some advise to solve my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: What problem do you have implementing this functionality? Without seeing what you've already tried, it is unlikely that we'll do a better job explaining than the Firebase documentation already does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only those keys, `783444` and `234567` in a `ListView`, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("Quiz").child("MCQ").child("Question").child("1831");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            list.add(key);
        }
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //Go to next activity
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: works but if i want to toast out the number how should i add in the public void onItemClick

Comment: Hi Xiao! Good to hear that it worked :) That's good news. You want to toast the number of what? But this sounds as an other question, which is different than the initial one and cannot be answered just in a comment. So in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I found out the ways already thanks for the code appreciate it. Happy hahaha